# Computing $\int_{\textbf{R}^n} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}$ for some $a\in \textbf{R}^n$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'd like to compute the following (Riemann) integral: 
$$\int_{\textbf{R}^n} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}$$
for some fixed $a\in \textbf{R}^n$.
To get started I computed the case in $\textbf{R}^2$, letting $a=(p,q)$ and writing $x=(x,y)$ (pardon the abuse of notation.) We can write $\|(x,y)\|^2=x^2+y^2.$ So that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\textbf{R}^2} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(p^2x^2+2pqxy+q^2y^2)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p^2x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2pqxy e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy\\&+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}q^2y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy.
\end{align*}
Applying Fubini's theorem and using the well known Gaussian integral, the first integral summand is 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p^2x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy=p^2\int_{\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dy=2\pi p^2.$$
By symmetry, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}q^2y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy=2\pi q^2$$
If we factor out $2pq$ from the middle summand integral, and apply Fubini's theorem, we get 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2pqxy e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dxdy=2pq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dy.$$
Both integrals are of odd functions taken over a domain symmetric about 0, so they both vanish. Then we get
$$\int_{\textbf{R}^2} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}=2\pi(p^2+q^2).$$

This leads me to the following guess in the $\textbf{R}^n$ case: if $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, then 
$$\int_{\textbf{R}^n} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}=(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2).$$
The justification for this guess would similar to the result I got from the above computation: if we write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n),$ then we can split the integral by linearity according to the multinomial expansion of $\langle x,a \rangle ^2.$ In this expansion, all integrals of functions containing products of mixed $x_i$'s will vanish, since the maximal power of any term of mixed $x_i$'s will be 1 by the definition of squares of multinomials. This will leave only integrals of squares of one such $x_i$. Splitting each such integral by Fubini's theorem and evaluating will result in an $n$-fold product of $\sqrt{2\pi},$ multiplied by the corresponding square $a_i^2.$

Is this guess justified correctly? If not, any hints in the right direction would be appreciated. I have a suspicion this is not the slickest way to justify this.

Comment: Your justification is correct. Another way to figure why the cross terms cancel is to treat the exponential term as the joint distribution of many independent Gaussians. Then $$\int x_i x_j e^{-\|x\|^2/2}= E[X_i X_j]=E[X_i]E[X_j]=0 $$ You can use an argument drawing on the same concept to calculate the integrals with $x_i^2$ in them.

Comment: @paulinho Thanks. That's a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write $a = \alpha \mathbf{e}$ where $\alpha^2 = \|a\|^2= a_1^2 + \dots + a_n^2$ and $\mathbf{e}$ is a unit vector. The integral become 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x,a \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2} = 
\alpha^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x,\mathbf{e} \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2} \, .
$$
Next apply a rotation that maps $\mathbf{e}$ to $\mathbf{e_1}$, the first unit vector, and leaves the space that is perpendicular to $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{e_1}$ unchanged. This does not change the value of the integral, which now takes the form
$$
\alpha^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x,\mathbf{e} \rangle ^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}  = \alpha^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_1^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2} 
$$
The integrand now is $x_1^2 \cdot e^{-x_1^2/2} \cdot e^{-x_2^2/2} \cdot \dots \cdot
 e^{-x_n^2/2}$. By Fubini's Theorem, therefore 
$$
\alpha^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_1^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\| ^2}  = \alpha^2 \left(2 \pi\right)^{n/2}
$$
which is the expression that you derived.

Comment: $\alpha$ should be $(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2)^{1/2}$, correct? Otherwise your answer would not be the same as mine

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. I fixed it now